# How to stack displacement nodes?

Tags: texturing, shaders, normals, displacement

When using displacement modifiers, you can use the resulting mesh normals of the first displacement as the base for the second, such that the end result is a 3 dimensional displacement.

For example, these 2 modifiers only use grayscale gradient textures :

[image]

The "Vector Displacement" node allows for that but what would be the node setup to stack 2 grayscale textures to get the same behavior ?

In case you want it, here's the file used for the above gif : [image]

Comment: I thought you might be able to use a bump node to generate normals for the second displacement, but it looks like displacement is evaluated before any bump nodes, regardless of node flow (for evaluation of bump + displacement, I imagine.)  With the way Blender handles this, I don't believe there's a general, bakeless solution.  But it would be possible if you were to bake the normals you get from the first node-based displacement, which you could then use as vectors to scale for your second displacement.